# Regarding Apache on Mac OS X Lion

Tags: python, macos, apache, encoding, utf-8

I'm fairly new to Apache as a whole, since I've only just started Web Developing, so please ask for more details if I haven't provided enough.

I am using the out-of the box Apache that ships with Lion, and I have created a Python application that, every once in a while, needs to print out a UTF-8 character.

However, no matter what method I use, or how much I try, when ever I try to print out a UTF-8 character, it will throw out a `500 Internal Server Error`, and I will be left with nothing.

The various things I've tried:

- Printing out the character directly from the Python code (With the `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the top of the code.)
- Printing out the character using the `.decode('utf-8')` function. (Which results in printing out 3 seperate characters.)
- Printing out a placeholder, and then printing out Jquery which would replace the placeholder with the Symbol (And the page throws up an Internal Server Error)
- Printing out a placeholder, and then printing out a link to a Jquery script which would replace it. (Firebug says that Firefox gets a 500 Server Error when trying to access the script.)

I cannot think of anything else.
That's why I've asked here.

Any suggestions?

Thanks
~DragonXDoom

EDIT: After trying out Will's suggestion below, I now get the following error.

```
<type 'exceptions.UnicodeDecodeError'>: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
  args = ('ascii', '\xe2\x80\xa2', 0, 1, 'ordinal not in range(128)')
  encoding = 'ascii'
  end = 1
  message = ''
  object = '\xe2\x80\xa2'
  reason = 'ordinal not in range(128)'
  start = 0
```

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Python as a web language, but the second approach might work correctly if you send the correct UTF-8 content-type/charset HTTP header or equivalent HTML meta tag in your request. The browser is probably trying to use ISO-8859-1 to decode it.

Comment: As I said, I'm quite new to this, so can you give an example of such a meta tag or header?

Comment: This actually has nothing to do with Apache, or Mac OS X. :) Just python and unicode, I suggest using those two tags instead.

Comment: I think it has something to do with Apache, since I tried running the exact same script in Terminal, and it prints out the UTF-8 characters fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must read http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html so that you have some understanding of the general problem.

Once you've understood that, then you should learn how to handle unicode correctly in Python, I think the following website should be useful, although lengthy: http://boodebr.org/main/python/all-about-python-and-unicode

Whatever you do, please do NOT skimp or skip on understanding unicode - otherwise you will continue to have subtle issues.

Furthermore, you state that you've attempted to use .decode('utf-8') - this won't work if python has /already/ understood the data as unicode - you want to *encode* it!

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on my comment, you can tell the browser which encoding the page is being transmitted in either with an HTTP header:

```
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

or with an equivalent `<meta>` tag (which goes in the `<head>` section in your HTML):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" value="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

This way it *should* correctly interpret the UTF-8 characters it receives. (`text/html` can be replaced with a more appropriate MIME type.)

As for the first attempt, with `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`, I expect this is because Apache doesn't know how to interpret UTF-8 source files.

Again, I'm not really familiar with running Python on Apache, but maybe this will be of some help!

Comment: Ok, I've tried this.
But now I get an error that is on the main question.